# UnsupportedOperationException using proguard

Tags: android, proguard, tail-recursion, android-proguard

I'm having following problem running proguard:

```
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Method must be overridden in [proguard.optimize.TailRecursionSimplifier$MyRecursionChecker] if ever called
     at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitAnyConstant(SimplifiedVisitor.java:120)
     at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitAnyRefConstant(SimplifiedVisitor.java:177)
     at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitAnyMethodrefConstant(SimplifiedVisitor.java:192)
     at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitInterfaceMethodrefConstant(SimplifiedVisitor.java:198)
     at proguard.classfile.constant.InterfaceMethodrefConstant.accept(InterfaceMethodrefConstant.java:69)
     at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.constantPoolEntryAccept(ProgramClass.java:453)
     at proguard.optimize.TailRecursionSimplifier.visitConstantInstruction(TailRecursionSimplifier.java:155)
     at proguard.classfile.instruction.ConstantInstruction.accept(ConstantInstruction.java:157)
     at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.instructionsAccept(CodeAttribute.java:138)
     at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.instructionsAccept(CodeAttribute.java:110)
     at proguard.optimize.TailRecursionSimplifier.visitCodeAttribute(TailRecursionSimplifier.java:117)
     at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.accept(CodeAttribute.java:101)
     at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.attributesAccept(ProgramMethod.java:79)
     at proguard.classfile.attribute.visitor.AllAttributeVisitor.visitProgramMember(AllAttributeVisitor.java:95)
     at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitProgramMethod(SimplifiedVisitor.java:91)
     at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.accept(ProgramMethod.java:71)
     at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.methodsAccept(ProgramClass.java:504)
     at proguard.classfile.visitor.AllMethodVisitor.visitProgramClass(AllMethodVisitor.java:47)
     at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:346)
     at proguard.classfile.ClassPool.classesAccept(ClassPool.java:116)
     at proguard.optimize.Optimizer.execute(Optimizer.java:652)
     at proguard.ProGuard.optimize(ProGuard.java:306)
     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:115)
     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Does anybody knows how to solve this?